# DEXIE - A function whose decl ared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

Tags: angular, typescript, dexie

I'm trying to implement a function that check if a price is in a range.

The data are located in the IndexedDB and I'm using Dexie to work with it.

In this moment I can't compile my soluzion

```
public checkPrizeChange(codCli: string, codList: string, codArt: string, price: number): Observable<any> {

    this._WebDBService.Listino_Articoli.filter(function (i){
      return (i.codLis == codList && i.codArt == codArt);
    }).toArray().then(
      data => {
        if(data.length != 1)
        {
          return Observable.of(false)
        }
        else{
          if(data[0].prezzoMin >= price && data[0].prezzoMax <= price)
            return Observable.of(true)
          else
            return Observable.of(false)
        }
      }
    );
   }
```

I don't know what is the properly way to work with dexie...

I just have to check some fields in a row of a DexieTable, nothing hard and return an Observable...

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return` before this line:

```
return this._WebDBService.Listino_Articoli.filter(function (i){
```

Comment: now I get: Type 'Promise<Observab
le<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
But are you shure that is the properly method ?

Comment: Change your method return type to `Observable<boolean>`

Answer (score 1):

The Dexie method toArray() returns a Promise. You want to return an Observable.

Probably, you should do something like:

```
public checkPrizeChange(codCli: string, codList: string, codArt: string, price: number): Observable<boolean> {

  return Observable.fromPromise(this._WebDBService.Listino_Articoli.filter(i => i.codLis == codList && i.codArt == codArt).toArray().then(
    data => {
      if(data.length != 1)
      {
        return false;
      }
      else{
        if(data[0].prezzoMin >= price && data[0].prezzoMax <= price)
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Also, seems you could utilize a [compound index](http://dexie.org/docs/Compound-Index) "[codLis+codArt]" to speed up your query. If using Dexie 2.0, your query could be rewritten to utilize the index:

```
this._WebDBService.Listino_Articoli.where({
  codLis: codLis,
  codArt: codArt
}).toArray()
```

Comment: Listino_Articoli: '[codLis+codArt], prezzo, preSco, preScoTes, codSco, prePro, valSco, perSco1, perSco2, perSco3, datIniSco, datFinSco, prezzoMin, prezzoMax',

Comment: That is the table with the composed key !